# Can't verify CSRF: rails_admin with rails_api

Tags: rails-admin, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I created a fresh rails-api app and added an address model to it and then installed rails_admin. And whenever I try to add rows, I get `422`s

I can see that CSRF token has been sent in the JSON, but it says its invalid.

```
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"9PP0EREx/cTK2TVtMp38ao/U9QCu6pjwmvV4fxIGEwTjZvGUfTcz7hpWL85UR/7qO3w+kytA2HD98+u7yiy3wg==", "address"=>{"door_no"=>"229", "street"=>"", "area"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "pin"=>"", "code"=>""}, "return_to"=>"", "_save"=>"", "model_name"=>"address"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)
```

What could be wrong? Something in the gem maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I initially thought that the issue was same that I encountered some months before, posted [on Github](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2830), however even after downgrading to `1.1.0` I had same issues. Currently I'm on Rails `5.1.2` and Rails Admin `1.2.0`.

> Setting `config.api_only = false` solves the problem

`api-only` mode seems to clash with some csrf verification stuff, which started to work pretty perfect as soon as I changed the flag.